# Regex ignore match if substring of a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to match a text string in javascript as long as it isn't a substring of a predefined word.

E.g. let's say we have these words in the file and even if there's a match, I don't want the word **blue** to show up in the search;

```
value
lunar
blue
clue
```

So if the user searches for **lu**, all the words other than blue should show up. If the user were to search for **ue**, only value and clue should be matched.

I tried doing a negative look ahead like this;

```
((?!blue)lu)
```

Didn't work though and I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: So if I understand correct, you want `clue` to be in result, but not `blue`. Am I right?

Comment: You have to use word boundaries : `\blu\b`

Comment: Request for clarification,  *I don't want the word blue...* then why only word *blue*?

Comment: @revo this was just a simplified example of what I want to do. In any case, I want to know how to do, I don't have anything against the word blue ;)

Comment: I meant why you specified only word *blue* while there are more words regarding same requirements in your example. More better I should ask what do you want to match eventually?

Comment: @revo I hope my edit clarifies a bit better

Comment: @Rajesh if the user were to search for lu, I want value, lunar and clue to show up. If the user searched for ue, I want value and clue to show up.

Comment: See @anubhava's answer. It seems to be a solution to your problem.

Comment: To be honest, I dont see a pattern in your requirement. I mean why so hard on blue? Let poor guy join some list... :-p

Answer (score 7):

You need to place `\w*` to match 0 or more word characters between negative lookahead and your search string.

With `lu` as search string:

```
/\b(?!blue)\w*lu\w*/
```

With `ue` as search string:

```
/\b(?!blue)\w*ue\w*/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/29dQ0R/5)

Actual Javascript code can be this:

```
var kw = "lu"; or "ue"
var re = new RegExp("\\b(?!blue)\\w*" + kw + "\\w*");
```

Comment: This user has a nasty history of asking questions and not bothering to accepting answers.